# Proper design of command line parameters?

Tags: java, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have a Java class API that looks like this:

```
boolean categoryAdd( String name, String description, String user );
```

and I need to create a command line equivalent for it.

How would the command line parameters look like?

Like this

```
-categoryadd name description user
```

or like this

```
-categoryadd -categoryname name -categorydescription description -categoryuser user
```

or like this

```
-categoryadd -categoryname=name -categorydescription=description -categoryuser=user
```

or something else?

Comment: Use a framework like [Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/)

Comment: Thanks. It's not about framework, it's about how to design the command.

Comment: Yes but that framework solves that problem for you. It supports different types of options (POSIX, GNU Long options, etc).

Comment: There is a problem: this code has been transfered to me, and I can't change much of it. I can't switch to new CL framework. However, I'd like to, at least, design my command in a proper way.

Comment: I've never been a fan of answers that basically say: "Let this do it for you" because it really means, "Don't bother learning, someone else has done it already"

Comment: @zero298 Maybe that's why I didn't post an answer but just a comment, as a suggestion. Is that OK?

Comment: Don't use `Commons CLI` it is buggy and crap, use one of the many **other** more modern not buggy/not crap frameworks and follow Unix command line standards. Just don't use `Commons CLI`, anything else is better!

Comment: Shorter is better (less typing), so my vote is for the first option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java command line string separated by spaces so when you call you method from CLI like:

> java MyClass categoryadd name description user

, in you main class you will recieve args with 4 values:

- categoryadd
- name
- description
- user

This way it will be easy for to manipulate (validate) parameters, because you don't need to do additional manipulations to extract passed variables.

From other hand from user side without additional information it pretty confusing what kind of parameters to pass and in which order.
In your 2nd and 3rd propositions you "helping" user to determine which parameters he passes. I prefer the 3rd proposition with equals, because it will be easy to parse the:
you will receive parameters like:

- -categoryadd
- -categoryname=name
- -categorydescription=description
- -categoryuser=user

Now you delay on first and can parse key-value with string.split(=) way.
Your 2nd option also can be done but I think it is more tricky

Comment: I went with 1st solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Common usage dictates that single character (short) options are in the form of `-v` and multi-character (long) options are in the form of `--verbose` as examples.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface

Seriously consider using a CLI Parsing library that will handle all this for you and more.

My preference is [JSAP](http://www.martiansoftware.com/jsap/), it is feature complete, stable and highly useful. Newer libraries use `@Annotations` and other things but this gets it done for me.